# Call HashMap Value from Another Method

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to call the values of the hashmap from another method. I need the values `1, "Twin", 200, 200` to be printed instead of `"YES"` when `TW` has been called in `ref`. However keep in mind I have to leave `setupMuseum` as `private`. I've tried different approaches but each time ended up with an error.

```java
  private void setupMuseum() {
        HashMap<String, MUSEUM>Museum= new HashMap<String, MUSEUM>();
        
        Museum.put("TW", new MUSEUM(1, "Twin", 200, 200)); 
    }
```

```java
public String getMuseumDetails(String ref) {
        if ("TW".equals(ref) ){
            System.out.println("YES");
            
            
        }else
            return "!";
            
        return "\nNo such thing";
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `setupMuseum()` method is useless as is. It creates a `Map` that is not even returned and which is also not an instance variable. You need to return the created `Map` and then you can print whatever is in there:

```java
private Map<String, MUSEUM> setupMuseum() {
    HashMap<String, MUSEUM> Museum = new HashMap<String, MUSEUM>();
    Museum.put("TW", new MUSEUM(1, "Twin", 200, 200)); 

    return Museum;
}
```

Then in your `getMuseumDetails()` method, you need to call `setupMuseum()` and print the values:

```java
public String getMuseumDetails(String ref) {
    if ("TW".equals(ref) ){
        HashMap<String, MUSEUM> museum = getMuseumDetails();
        System.out.println(museum.get("TW"));
    } else {
        return "!";
    }
    
    return "\nNo such thing";  // This is unreachable
}
```

This is assuming that both methods are in the same file, so that `setupMuseum()` can be reached within `getMuseumDetails()`. This also assumes that your `MUSEUM` class has an appropriate `toString()` implementation that actually includes all its properties.

---

As side notes please keep the following in mind:

- Usually, variables in Java follow snakeCase, so you should name `Museum` as `museum`.
- Java classes should not have their name as uppercase, so you should name `MUSEUM` as `Museum`.
- You should strive to use Java interfaces instead of concrete implementations. This means that you should use `Map<String, MUSEUM> Museum = new HashMap<String, MUSEUM>();` instead of `HashMap<String, MUSEUM> Museum = new HashMap<String, MUSEUM>();` so that you declare the variable as a `Map` (the interface) instead of as a `HashMap` (the concrete implementation).